# Force decimals in html inputs with html or js? Mask

Tags: jquery, html, input, mask

So I have an input, and by default I want it to have the value 0.00. Easy enough.

When a user starts typing, I want to fill from the right. So when they enter "5", the input will show "0.05." Then they enter a zero and the input changes to "0.50" and so on. So if the user wanted to enter 5 dollars, they would just enter 5, 0, 0.

Is there a pretty straightforward way to do this? I have tried searching around but I think I'm missing the right keywords for my search phrases. I don't know what to call this, so sorry if this is a duplicate.

Thanks.

Comment: What you are talking about is called masking.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the title to help others know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

meioMask [<sup>site</sup>](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/) [<sup>github</sup>](https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask) has what you are searching for. [Demo](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/#mm_standalone)
on their site.

Comment: This looks like a fine example too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with jQuery and a jQuery plugin.

A simple search yielded this result: https://github.com/madeinstefano/Decimal-Mask

**EDIT:**  After running this in a Fiddle, it seems that the plugin I posted does not do exactly what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/YAQMS/

---

**UPDATE:** I've found a better solution - https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YAQMS/1/

Comment: That forces a decimal point, but not really what I was asking about. This functionality would allow me to set 999.99 as a mask and then restrict the input to three digits before a decimal. It doesn't autofill the decimal nor can it force input from the right.

Comment: @RKS Forcing input from the right can only be done with CSS, if you look at my fiddle, you will see how I did that. Also, you can use HTML to set default values. http://jsfiddle.net/YAQMS/3/

Comment: That looks perfect. Thanks. Although, I don't see the difference between the two inputs on your last fiddle above. They both look like they will do exactly what I need. I also didn't know about the direction property. I will have to read up on that too since the W3C sample page makes it look no different than text-align: right. Thanks.

Comment: @RKS The top one is an [HTML5 Placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder), and the bottom one just has it's value set. The major difference, for your purpose, being that only the latter will send its default 0's on form submit. The CSS [Direction](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp) property changes the direction of the text (i.e. left-to-right, right-to-left).

Comment: Thanks. I saw the placeholder and value I just wasn't sure what you were showing me there. I did also see the difference between direction and alignment in regards to your fiddle. Very good and informative.

Comment: Hmmm. After experimenting it seems I don't understand what this is doing. As per your fiddle, it is impossible to type values like 0.50. Upon entering the zero, it will move the decimal to 5.0 instead of 0.50. Changing the value in the last function from 9.99 to 99.99 allows for 0.50, but pressing another zero, expecting 5.00, you get 50.0 instead. I've found that's one of the problems with the direction:rtl but even removing that still has kinks I'm investigating.

Comment: @RKS Yup, you would have to enter '050'. I'm sure there is a way to pad the numbers to the left with zeros. Just takes some experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

You can align input to right in your CSS like so:

```
input#my_input {
  text-align: right;
}
```

And for input masking, here's a Google search that might help: https://www.google.com/search?q=html+input+masking

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the phrase "mask." That's a term I was missing and now I can search a bit more. The CSS text-align property doesn't do what I need in this case. I don't need it align to the right, I need it to fill from the right.

Comment: @RKS Ah, I see what you're saying.  I should have read more closely.  I would think something like that would be a part of a good input masking library.

Comment: I would think so too. Now that I know what to search for I'm sure I will be more successful looking for it. Sometimes the right words are all you need.